# SQL select decimal from String contain Date

Tags: sql, substring, sql-server-2016

I want only numeric decimal else integer value from given string

Current Table Output :

```
        Column
        10.40  (10/14 after @ 10.3)  
        10.1%
        10%
        10/12/2017 10.45
        8.2  10/12
        15.20% 10/12/17
        11/12
        > 10.50
        < 50.10
```

Expected Output :

```
        10.40
        10.1
        10
        10.45
        8.2
        15.20
        NULL
        NULL
        NULL
```

tried query :

```
        declare @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(max) ='completed 11/12 at Dr Lemons office'

         select 
        stuff(stuff( @strAlphaNumeric+'x',patindex('%[0-9][^0-9.]%', @strAlphaNumeric+'x') + 1, len( @strAlphaNumeric), '' ), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',  @strAlphaNumeric) - 1,      
        '')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: SQL is not the best tool for these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

First, as HoneyBadger suggested `SQL` is not right tool for that. But, the alternate way

```
select case when TRY_CONVERT(money, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9./]%', Col1), LEN(Col1)))) is null then
             cast(REPLACE(Col1,  LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9./]%', Col1), LEN(Col1)+1)), '') as varchar)
      else
             cast(TRY_CONVERT(money, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9./]%', Col1), LEN(Col1)))) as varchar)  end [Col1] from <table>
```

Result :

```
Col1
10.40 
10.1
10
10.45
8.2  
15.20
BLANK
BLANK
```